# How to set drawableRIGHTon Android button?(IMAGE DINAMICALLY)

Tags: android

```
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
 button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, drawable, null);
```

This work but i would all dinamically.

```
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.path);
 button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, drawable, null);
```

where path is a string that contains a name of image..
thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you are trying to get drawable by the image name. right?
If so,

```
int imageResource = res.getIdentifier(path, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(imageResource);
```

then assign the button drawable...

Comment: OK, than i set this image in the right of botton..it`s correct?  Buttò.setCompound...(.,..,imageResourse,..). I simplify the code on the top

Comment: no, the code doesn't work, i have this error: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000

Comment: i would an image in the right of button, the image is in the variable path